# How to handle animation completion in view controllers with custom animator?

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, ios7

I implement custom animator conformed to **UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning** protocol.

In

```
- (void)animateTransition:(id <UIViewControllerContextTransitioning>)transitionContext
```

i make nice transition and also create and add to container new **UIView** (with blur effect). I need to handle this ***view*** in **from** OR **to** view controllers.

So **my question** is *what the best way to handle animation completion event and this custom new view* in VCs?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I create protocol *AnimatorDelegate* and *delegate* property in animator. And add method like this to delegate protocol

```
-(void) animationEnded:(id<UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning>) animator andOverlay:(UIView*) overlay
```

Then I set **delegate** to specific VC during animator creation. Maybe anyone knows **built-in** way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

I think creating block for completion handler is better way to handle this.

Comment: delegate or completion block are much the same... is any way to use UIKit to catch this?